# API response is automatedly getting converted from int to string

Tags: php, json, rest

I have few rest API's which are written in core PHP. I am using this API's for IOS mobile application. But sometimes in the response, few variables are getting converted as Int to string data type. Which is stopping the execution of the application. When I print the response using print_r() the values coming out correctly, but when I echo the response using json_encode(), few int values are printing as string.

This issue is not happening all the time only sometimes I am mfacing this issue.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * From Table');
$stmt->execute(['value' => $_POST['value']]);
$rowvalue = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rowvalue as $type => $value) {
    if ($value === null) {
        $rowvalue[$type] = "";
    }
    if ($rowvalue["isotherfacilitycompatible"] === "") {
        $rowvalue["isotherfacilitycompatible"] = 0;
    }
    if ($rowvalue["serviceablevendor"] === "") {
        $rowvalue["serviceablevendor"] = "";
    }
    if($type == 'rmacreatedid'){
        $rowvalue[$type] = (int)$rowvalue[$type];
    }
}
$response["details"][$type] = $rowvalue[$type];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Can anyone give me any idea, what may be causing this issue.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: please edit your post and include that code with proper formatting

Comment: @Jerson please check now and give me some idea how to solve this issue. Thank you

Comment: Does the version of php have anything to do with this issue. My current php version is 7.0

Comment: Which values turn into strings? I assume some database column, which column and what is the column's type?

Comment: the column type is tinyint, it may contain 1 or 0. This  column is coming out as a string in response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode) with [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/json.constants.php#constant.json-numeric-check) flag:

```
    $result = array(
        'is_bool' => true,
        'user_id' => 121,
        'total_amount' => '431.65',
        'phone_number' => '9090909000'
    );
    echo json_encode($result,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me how to retain alphanumeric values as it is when I use JSON_NUMErIC_CHECK

Answer (score 0):

Note that since PHP 5.3.3, there's a flag for auto-converting numbers (the options parameter was added in PHP 5.3.0):

```
$arr = array( 'row_id' => '10', 'name' => 'John' );
echo json_encode( $arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); // {"row_id":10,"name":"John"}
```